# considering using Cross Apply but not sure

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, reporting, business-intelligence

This is my first question on stackoverflow and am looking forward to everyone's feedback and solutions.

I would put my current SQL skills at the lower end of intermediate.

Simple one for most of you: I need to write a query in an oracle SQL environment that returns all transactions after the active employees departure date.

Table looks like this:

```
| Name  | dept  | departure date |
| John  | Sales | 3.12.2014      | 
| David | IT    | 7.27.2014      | 
| Gary  | Audit | 12.5.2013      |
```

Transaction table

```
| TransID   | Emp Name | Amount | TransDate | 
| 1         | John     | 25.00  | 3.31.2014 | 
| 2         | David    | 30.00  | 8.13.204  | 
| 3         | Gary     | 15.00  | 1.1.2014  |
```

I'm trying to avoid a UNION ALL since the table has over 100+ employee records. On researching the use of CROSS APPLY it seemed like it could fit the situation. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Josh

Comment: What does your transactions table looks like?

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid a UNION ALL since the table has over 100+ employee records." - the implication is the choice of solution is dependent on the number of records in his table. Pointing out a fact is not 'belittling'.

Comment: @isim  
  
Table looks something like:  

Trans ID / Emp Name / Amount / Trans Date  
1 / John Doe / 25.00 / 3.31.2014  
2 / David Smith / 30.00 / 8.13.204  
3 / Gary Allen / 15.00 / 1.1.2014  
4 / John Doe / 80.00 / 2.28.2014  
5 / Eric Davis/ 25.00 / 5.21.2014  
6 / Steve Sanders / 73.00 / 10.31.2014  
7 / Joe Clark / 50.00 / 01.16.2014  
  
results should look like:  

Trans ID / Emp Name / Amount / Trans Date  
1 / John Doe / 25.00 / 3.31.2014  
2 / David Smith / 30.00 / 8.13.204  
3 / Gary Allen / 15.00 / 1.1.2014

Comment: @MitchWheat I think it was clear from the OPs post that they believed that the solution is dependent on size. I am quite sure you are articulate enough to leave out the condescending tone. In particular I think you could have eliminated "*and you think that's many?*" and made your point.

Comment: Sorry about the blob. Havent learned the site markup yet

Comment: "i'm trying to avoid" writing a giant query with UNION ALL statement for each employee. looking for something smarter since my skills still need some work.

Comment: @ Michael Petch: what's your point? I've told the poster that (1) 100+ is a trivial amount of rows, (2) I've told them their solution in this case is independent of the number of rows. Instead of harassing me, how about you post something useful? Point of diminishing return reached.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `join`:

```
select t.*
from employees e join
     transactions t
     on e.emp = t.emp and e.date < t.transdate;
```

You could write this using `apply`, but I think a `join` makes the intention more clear.

Comment: I can tell just by looking at this the method will work. Thanks for the help Mr. Linoff. You salvaged my 1st impression of stackoverflow. Lol